# Unicode Characters in GRASS ps.map instructions file

Tags: grass-gis, unicode

I am trying to put text on a ps.map generated map and the text contains the degrees symbol. I can insert the symbol into the instructions file, and it looks fine, but when I generate the map, the result is Â°

Here's the instruction:
text 99% 63% 60 °N
  fontsize 16
  ref left
end

Does anyone have advice on how to get unicode symbols to display correctly with ps.map?

Comment: [This](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3078) says to convert the encoding but it didn't work for me.